# Unable to execute a timeseries query using a timeuuid as the primary key

Tags: node.js, cassandra, time-series, cassandra-3.0, express-cassandra

My goal is to do a sum of the messages_sent and emails_sent per each DISTINCT provider_id value for a given time range (fromDate < stats_date_id < toDate), but without specifying a provider_id. In other words, I need to know about any and all Providers within the specified time range and to sum their messages_sent and emails_sent.

I have a Cassandra table using an express-cassandra schema (in Node.js) as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  fields: {
    stats_provider_id: {
      type: 'uuid',
      default: {
        '$db_function': 'uuid()'
      }
    },
    stats_date_id: {
      type: 'timeuuid',
      default: {
        '$db_function': 'now()'
      }
    },
    provider_id: 'uuid',
    provider_name: 'text',
    messages_sent: 'int',
    emails_sent: 'int'
  },
  key: [
    [
      'stats_date_id'
    ],
    'created_at'
  ],
  table_name: 'stats_provider',
  options: {
    timestamps: {
      createdAt: 'created_at', // defaults to createdAt
      updatedAt: 'updated_at' // defaults to updatedAt
    }
  }
}
```

To get it working, I was hoping it'd be as simple as doing the following:

```
let query = {
    stats_date_id: {
      '$gt': db.models.minTimeuuid(fromDate),
      '$lt': db.models.maxTimeuuid(toDate)
    }
  };
let selectQueries = [
    'provider_name',
    'provider_id',
    'count(direct_sent) as direct_sent',
    'count(messages_sent) as messages_sent',
    'count(emails_sent) as emails_sent',
  ];
  // Query stats_provider table
  let providerData = await db.models.instance.StatsProvider.findAsync(query, {select: selectQueries});
```

This, however, complains about needing to filter the results:
`Error during find query on DB -> ResponseError: Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance`.

I'm guessing you can't have a primary key and do date range searches on it?  If so, what is the correct approach to this sort of query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So while not having used Express-Cassandra, I can tell you that running a range query on your partition key is a hard "no."  The reason for this, is that Cassandra can't determine a single node for that query, so it has to poll every node.  As that's essentially a full scan of your table across multiple nodes, it throws that error to prevent you from running a bad query.

However, you *can* run a range query on a clustering key, provided that you are filtering on all of the keys prior to it.  In your case, if I'm reading this right, your PRIMARY KEY looks like:

`PRIMARY KEY (stats_date_id, created_at)`

That primary key definition is going to be problematic for two reasons:

1. `stats_date_id` is a TimeUUID.  This is *great* for data distribution.  But it sucks for query flexibility.  In fact, you will need to provide that exact TimeUUID value to return data for a specific partition.  As a TimeUUID has millisecond precision, you'll need to know the exact time to query ***down to the millisecond***.  Maybe you have the ability to do that, but usually that doesn't make for a good partition key.
2. Any rows underneath that partition (`created_at`) will have to share that exact time, which usually leads to a lot of 1:1 cardinality ratios for partition:clustering keys.

My advice on fixing this, is to partition on a date column that has a slightly lower level of cardinality.  Think about how many provider messages are usually saved within a certain timeframe.  Also pick something that won't store too many provider messages together, as you don't want unbound partition growth (Cassandra has a hard limit of 2 billion cells per partition).

Maybe something like: `PRIMARY KEY (week,created_at)`

So then your CQL queries could look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM stats_provider
WHERE week='201909w1'
  AND created_at > '20190901'
  AND created_at < '20190905';
```

**TL;DR;**

1. Partition on a time bucket not quite as precise as something down to the ms, yet large enough to satisfy your usual query.
2. Apply the range filter on the first clustering key, *within* a partition.